# Função parecida com strip_tags

Tags: php

Existe algum tipo de strip_tags que eu passo por parâmetro os elementos que eu NÃO permito?

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma string `"blabkabla<span>bla<span><p>blablabla<p>"`. Quero por exemplo remover apenas o `<p>` e não permitir, só o `<span>`.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que tens e como queres que fique? Estás a falar de HTML? de texto com tags? dificil perceber...

Comment: Suponhamos que eu tenha uma string "blabkabla<span>bla<span><p>blablabla<p>". Quero remover APENAS o <p> e não permitir só o <span>. É apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Sabes o que é o `DOMDocument` do PHP? acho que é esse o caminho...

Comment: De onde vem sua string? É um input?

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi muito bem o que você precisa, você só quer permitir o span em qualquer caso ou tem regra? Você ainda quer o conteúdo dentro do P? 
Qual o problema do `strip_tags($string, '<span>')`, acho mais valido você dizer o que vc permite, não?

Para só permitir o que você quer, use

```
strip_tags($string, '<span><br><qualquertag>')
```

Para criar uma lista de bloqueados use

```
preg_replace("/<\/?(p|embed|object|frameset|frame|iframe|meta|link|style)[^>]*>/", '', $string)
```